# Join One-To-Many, return minimum greater-than result

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, nested

I know the headline is complicated, but here is the situation:

I have a table of users like this:

```
 id     opened_at                
 32o   2/01/2018 00:00:00
```

And a table of users-groups like this:

```
 user_id     group_id
  32o         29834jb
```

And a full table of groups like this:

```
 group_id               group_ended_at
 29834jb               1/14/2018 00:00:00
 29834jb               2/14/2018 00:00:00
 29834jb               3/14/2018 00:00:00
 29834jb               4/14/2018 00:00:00
```

I want to join groups to users, but only return the minimum `group_ended_at` that is *greater* than the `opened_at` date for the user.

In other words, I want this result:

```
id           opened_at              group_id              group_ended_at
32o         2/01/2018 00:00:00       29834jb            2/14/2018 00:00:00
```

How would I go about that?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can build on your attempt: just add the date inequality condition to the join conditions, define the proper `group by` clause, and you are here:

```
SELECT u.id, u.opened_at, u.group_id, MIN(g.group_ended_at)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN groups g
    ON  u.group_id = g.group_id
    AND g.group_ended_at > u.opened_at
GROUP BY u.id, u.opened_at, u.group_id
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing pretty much this exact response. haha

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question that was originally asked.

I like a lateral join for this:

```
SELECT u.*, g.group_ended_at
FROM users u LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT MIN(g.group_ended_at) as group_ended_at
      FROM groups g
      WHERE u.group_id = g.group_id AND g.group_ended_at > u.opened_at
     ) g;
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, theres actually a table between users and groups, called user-groups. I'm trying to extrapolate your answer to work with that condition but not working yet. I've edited my question to show the full situation, in case you know how to change your answer to fit it